# When use NSTimer in classA then can't call any method from other place

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nstimer

Here is a code I call to run timer for calling "tick:" method in classA (it calls NOT in main thread):

```
    - (id)init {

        self = [super init];

        if (self != nil) {

        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f 
target:self selector:@selector(tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

        NSRunLoop *currentRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [currentRunLoop run];
        }

      return self;
    }
```

And timer works great. 
But when try to access to "doSomething" method (the same instance of class classA) in the same thread then method "doSomething" does't calls.

Why? How to fix the problem?

Comment: could you please elaborate your statement about "doSomething" - how does it relates to timer call? - timer is calling "tick" method.. i'm little confused about what you are explaining..

Comment: classA is a singleton. "doSomething" is a method I call: [[classA sharedClassA] doSomething]; "doSomething" is an empty method which do nothing. But it don't call.(

Comment: this init method does not create any singleton object though. There's got to be some problem with your shared object which "sharedClassA" is returning (probably it is nil) when you call [classA sharedClassA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How selector `doSomething:` is called?

Anyway you should try `[classAinstance performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doSomethingOnMainThread:) waitUntilDone:YESORNO];`

Comment: "doSomething" method is calling from another place by another object but in the same thread. "doSomthing" is just a stub.(empty method).

Comment: I agree this doesn't look like a singleton class. Can you provide more information about your problem...